# "More" close reason markup not rendered

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

I was reviewing in the close votes [review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/3569403) when I clicked the "more" link for the specific close reason. I saw the following:

[image]

As you can see, the markup is not rendering. There's also a call to `.AsHtml()` in there which is obviously not markup.

Browser is chrome 31.0.1650.63

Comment: possible duplicate of [Broken links in the Close review queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213380/broken-links-in-the-close-review-queue)

Comment: @Tim no, this one here is better with screenshot and more clear thus I voted to close the older one as dupe of this newer report. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard This one is older, actually :P

Comment: @Mansfield oh my, THREE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed in build rev `2013.12.23.1803` on meta and `2013.12.23.1263` on sites.