# Broken links in the Close review queue

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, vote-to-close

The text when reviewing Close Votes in /review is broken on ebooks.stackexchange.com as below:

[image]

This text is only visible when you click on the "more" link. Also replicated on MSO.

Comment: Dupped on [SO] as well.

Comment: Repo'd, right...?

Comment: looking fixing...

Comment: @Flyk Yep, that's what I meant, sorry :)